# Creating emacs mode: defining indentation

Tags: emacs, programming-languages, lisp, indentation, mode

I'm writing a simple mode for a Lisp-like language, and am having trouble setting up indentation. I've been following the [emacswiki mode tutorial](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial).

However, I can't figure out how to adapt their example indentation to my needs because they don't do any form of counting.

Basically, I just need to add 2 spaces to my indentation count every time I see a `{` or `(`, even if there are multiple on the same line, and subtract 2 spaces when I see closures of the above. I'm new to elisp; how can I adapt their example to count braces and brackets?

For convenience, here is the code they are using (for a non-bracket language):

```lisp
(defun wpdl-indent-line ()
  "Indent current line as WPDL code"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (if (bobp)  ; Check for rule 1
      (indent-line-to 0)
    (let ((not-indented t) cur-indent)
      (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*END_") ; Check for rule 2
      (progn
        (save-excursion
          (forward-line -1)
          (setq cur-indent (- (current-indentation) default-tab-width)))
        (if (< cur-indent 0)
        (setq cur-indent 0)))
        (save-excursion 
          (while not-indented
            (forward-line -1)
            (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*END_") ; Check for rule 3
                (progn
                  (setq cur-indent (current-indentation))
                  (setq not-indented nil))
                    ; Check for rule 4
              (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\(PARTICIPANT\\|MODEL\\|APPLICATION\\|WORKFLOW\\|ACTIVITY\\|DATA\\|TOOL_LIST\\|TRANSITION\\)")
                  (progn
                    (setq cur-indent (+ (current-indentation) default-tab-width))
                    (setq not-indented nil))
                (if (bobp) ; Check for rule 5
                    (setq not-indented nil)))))))
      (if cur-indent
          (indent-line-to cur-indent)
        (indent-line-to 0))))) ; If we didn't see an indentation hint, then allow no indentation
```

How can I just implement lisp-like indentation (but also with curly braces)?

Comment: Why not just look at the source of `lisp-indent-function`?

Comment: abo-abo, I can't find an uncompiled definition of that function.

Comment: Install emacs from source, then you'll find the definitions easily with `describe-function`.

Comment: As far as I can see,`lisp-indent-function` is part of a family of complex indent functions within `lisp-mode.el` and I'm not sure what to do with them...

Comment: You don't have to understand it completely to use it. In fact you can probably use it without modification.

Comment: two problems--I'm not sure how to "use" it, and lisp isn't exactly right because it doesn't recognize curly braces.

Comment: It recognizes them fine as far as I can see: the Elisp indentation for { looks fine to me. The indentation of `clojure-mode` is only slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something simple for a Lisp-style language, I suggest you start with `(syntax-ppss)` which returns the "parsing state" at point.  The first element of that state is the current paren-nesting depth.  While I used the word "paren", this doesn't really count parens but counts those chars which the syntax-table defines as paren-like, so if you set your syntax-table such that { and } are declared as paren-like, then those will also be counted.

So you could start with something like

```
(defun foo-indent-function ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (indent-line-to (* 2 (car (syntax-ppss))))))
```

Do not define this as interactive, since the way to use it is by adding

```
(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) #'foo-indent-function)
```

in your major-mode function.

But maybe a better option is to simply do:

```
(require 'smie)
...
(define-derived-mode foo-mode "Foo"
  ...
  (smie-setup nil #'ignore)
  ...)
```

This will use an indentation step of 4 (configured in `smie-indent-basic`).

Comment: That's almost perfect! I use the former function at it is great. Would you add a link or brief explanation about how to define/extend syntax-ppss? Also, I notice my closing curly brace is still indented here, when I would like it to be flush-left. Any suggestion?

Comment: Extending syntax-ppss is not really an option.  Using SMIE is preferable in this sense, because it is meant to be extended.  Also SMIE should handle the "closing brace should be flush-left" for you by default.